# HTML slider causing IE script error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-9

I have a simple HTML5 page that I'm building to figure some things out with sliders. They seem to be fine in the latest versions of Chrome (13+) and Firefox (4+). However, IE9 is giving me the following message:

"Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls."

Before I hit "Allow Blocked Content", the sliders do now show up. After I hit allow, they work just fine.

Any idea's why IE is having problems?

Below is the code for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/fd-slider/js/fd-slider.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/fd-slider/css/fd-slider.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/fd-slider/css/demo.css" />
</head>
<body>
<p>
    The following slider has the &#8220;forceValue&#8221; parameter set to TRUE, which
    forces the associated text input to show a valid value.
</p>
<label for="inputTest6" id="inputTest6Label">
    Range: 1 to 5 in steps of 1
</label>
<p>
    <input name="inputTest6" id="inputTest6" type="text" title="Range: 1 to 5 in steps of 1" value="2"  maxlength="6" />
</p>
<script> 
      fdSlider.createSlider({
        // Associate an input
        inp:document.getElementById("inputTest6"),
        // Declare a step
        step:1, 
        // Declare a maxStep
        maxStep:1,
        // Min value
        min:1,
        // Max value
        max:5,
        // Use the "tween to click point" animation
        animation:"tween",
        // Force the associated input to have a valid value
        forceValue:true
        });
      </script>
<p>
    The following slider has been associated with a <code>&lt;select&gt;</code>.
</p>
<label for="selectTest1" id="selectTest1Label">
    Select List with five options
</label>
<p>
    <select name="selectTest1" id="selectTest1">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4" selected>Four</option>
        <option value="5">Five</option>
    </select>
</p>
<script> 
      fdSlider.createSlider({
        // Associate a select list
        inp:document.getElementById("selectTest1"),
        // Use the tween animation
        animation:"tween",
        // Keep the form element, in this case a select list, visible
        hideInput:false,
        // Give it the className "v-s2" which will make the slider 160px in height
        classNames:"v-s2"
        });
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try loading the script from the same domain as the page?

Answer (score -2):

This will fix the problem:  Go to Tools->Internet Options->Advanced Tab, scroll to the Security section and check 'Allow active content to run in files on My Computer'.

Comment: The scripts are hosted in another domain, not on My Computer. And even if this worked, it would be not acceptable for production websites to require users to change their default security settings or click through a banner each time when they visit the website